# Getting to the next key in an array

Tags: php

Let's assume I know that there is key "twoVal", but I do not know what is after it. How do I get to the next key for that matter? Shoud I know the position of key "twoVal"? Or there is another way around?

```
$arr = array('Cool Viski' => array('oneVal' => '169304',
                                   'twoVal' => '166678',
                                   'threeVal' => '45134'));
```

Answer (score 17):

```
$keys = array_keys($arr['Cool Viski']);
$position = array_search('twoVal', $keys);
if (isset($keys[$position + 1])) {
    $keyAfterTwoVal = $keys[$position + 1];
}
```

Comment: I think it'd be more intelligent to do whatever the OP is trying to do another way than nitty gritty array manipulation, but it answers the question. :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do and so much cleaner. Thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array('Cool Viski' => array('oneVal' => '169304',
                                   'twoVal' => '166678',
                                   'threeVal' => '45134'));
foreach($arr as $s=>$v){
    foreach($v as $val){
        if(key($v) == "twoVal"){
            $t=next($v);
            print "next key: ".key($v)."\n";
            print "next key value is: ".$t."\n";;
        }else{
            next($v);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You might be interested in the various [array seeking functions](https://www.php.net/next), **but** unless a PHP array is indexed only by integers there's no guarantee of order on the keys.

Comment: Taken from http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php: `An array in PHP is actually an ordered map.` I'd say that's a guarantee on the order of the keys.

Comment: Also, this is not really a way to solve the given problem, seeing that you'd first need to get the internal pointer to the element with the known key, which can't be efficiently done as far as I can see from what you're linking to.