# Can a PHP class return an array of classes without calling methods or variables?

Tags: php, class, oop, php-8, php-8.1

Within PHP, I'd like to be able to iterate over a collection of classes to help with settings, inserting, and validating values. Using a class as a type in method args would make the code more strict which would help avoiding bugs.

I am able to access the collection but only through a public array or method (`$values->array` or `$values->get()`).
I would like to be able to use `$values` directly for cleaner code. For example, to access a reference, I'd need to use `$values->array[0]` or `$values->get()[0]` instead of `$values[0]`. How can this be achieved with PHP?

**Expected usage:**

```php
$values = new Values(
    new Value('foo', 'bar'),
    new Value('foo2', 'bar2'),
);

function handleValues(Values $exampleValues): void
{
    foreach ($exampleValues as $exampleValue) {
        //do something with $exampleValue->field, $exampleValue->value
    }
}

handleValues($values);
```

**Classes:**

```php
class Values
{
    public array $array;

    public function __construct(Value... $value){
        $this->array = $value;
    }
}

class Value
{
    public string $field;
    public mixed $value;

    public function __construct(string $field, mixed $value)
    {
        $this->field = $field;
        $this->value = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I understand the question, and I have a couple of ideas, but I'm not sure of the best way to answer because I'm having trouble seeing what it's for exactly. Can you add a small example of how a theoretical solution would be used?

Comment: @MCSharp: If I understand correctly you would like to have a typed array. This does not exist in PHP. I would recommend to extend the class _Values_ from _ArrayIterator_ (but I second _Don't Panic_ that an example would be nice to better understand your issue).

Comment: Added an example. Having access directly to the array would prevent creating additional variables or calling `->array` every time I'd need to access the objects.

Comment: Look at the iterator interface which `Values` would implement: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php (for the iterating example).

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking of suggesting implementing the Iterator interface, as well as the ArrayAccess interface. You might find it more trouble than it's worth just to avoid using `->array`, (it will take quite a bit of extra code to implement these interfaces) but that would let you effectively use your Values objects like arrays.

Comment: I do think the examples helped to clarify your goal. Thanks for adding them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using foreach over an object implementing ArrayAccess and Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9973080/1426539)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions. I think implementing iterators are overkill. I'm just looking for a way to return the same output as `$values = [new Value()]` when using `$values = new Values(new Value())`. I thought this might be possible with magic methods but not getting success.

Comment: If part of the reason you want this is to enforce types in methods that take multiple values, arrays can still be used. if you use a variadic function such as your Values constructor, you can pass an array of values of that type with argument unpacking. For example: https://3v4l.org/aL8J0 (Apologies if you already know this.)

Comment: @Don'tPanic thanks for providing the example. That solution might work if there is only one arg but not in this case: https://3v4l.org/fR6pX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you really want is a typed array, but there is no such thing in PHP.

There *is* support for *documenting* typed arrays in a lot of static analysis tools and IDEs, using "PHPDoc syntax" like this:

```
/** @param Value[] $values */
function foo(array $values) {}
```

---

If you want an object that can be looped with `foreach`, the simplest way is to implement [the `IteratorAggregate` interface](https://www.php.net/IteratorAggregate), and use it to wrap the internal array in [an `ArrayIterator` object](https://php.net/ArrayIterator):

```
class Values implements IteratorAggregate
{
    private array $array;

    public function __construct(Value... $value){
        $this->array = $value;
    }
    
    public function getIterator(): Iterator {
        return new ArrayIterator($this->array);
    }
}

$values = new Values(
    new Value('foo', 'bar'),
    new Value('foo2', 'bar2'),
);

foreach ( $values as $value ) {
    var_dump($value);
}
```

---

If you want an object that can be referenced into with `[...]` syntax, implement [the `ArrayAccess` interface](https://php.net/ArrayAccess). There are four methods, but each is trivial to implement for this case, and there's an example in the manual.

---

There's also a built-in [`ArrayObject` class](https://php.net/ArrayObject) that implements both these interfaces (and a few more), which you can extend to get a lot of array-like behaviour in one go.

---

On the other hand, if all you want is to validate that the array contains only a specific type, then just do that. A one-line version would be:

```
$valid = array_reduce($values, fn($valid, $next) => $valid && $next instanceof Value, true);
```

Or a slightly more efficient version for large arrays (because it stops looping completely when it finds an invalid item):

```
$valid = true;
foreach ( $values as $next ) {
    if ( ! $next instanceof Value ) {
         $valid = false;
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the functionality I am looking for. Thanks for providing the examples. One note, `getIterator(): Iterator` should be `getIterator(): ArrayIterator`

Comment: @MCSharp That's up to you - `: Iterator` promises that this class, and any child classes, return some descendant of `Iterator`, which is true. It could also say `Traversable` (the return value required by the interface), or `ArrayIterator`, since those are both also true.